# How do I check to see if a registry entry exists?

Tags: vb.net, registry

I'm trying to see if a registry key exists. If it does, I do on thing, if not, I do something else. I've tried different things, but so far none have worked.

I've tried:

```
If My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.GetValue("MySubKey", True) Is Nothing Then
```

Also, I've tried to see if `regKey` var is nothing. And a few others I can't remember.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx you shold not get an exception if the key does not exist.

Comment: Hi.. thanks for the answer. I'm working on it now, but have to leave for a bit. Will let you know something then. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a Registry key exists you can use this...

```
  'Obtain an instance of RegistryKey for the CurrentUser registry root. 
   Dim rkCurrentUser As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser
  ' Obtain the key (read-only) and display it.
   If rkCurrentUser IsNot Nothing Then
      Dim rkTest As RegistryKey = rkCurrentUser.OpenSubKey("MySubKey")

      'Check and make sure we have something...
      If rkTest IsNot Nothing Then
         'You have something then...

         rkTest.Close 'Close it, this is important...
      Else
         'You do not have anything...
      End If 

      rkCurrentUser.Close 'Close this after you are done...
   Else
      'Failed to get instance of registry for the current user...
   End If
```

There are other ways as well, but let me know how this works out for you...

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was having a hard time getting Olivier's answer to work (I'm sure it's pilot error, my fault). But I got yours working pretty fast. Thanks so much for the help and... have a great day/night.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks @jumper, and no thanks to MS!  :}