# Can't find registry key using GetValue

Tags: vb.net, registry

Our VB.net application relies on a 3rd party DLL. We call it with:

```
DLLType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("APLW.WSEngine")
```

I'd like to first check to see if it has been registered properly. I poked about in Regedit, and sure enough, the key is where I would expect it to be:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\APLW.WSEngine
```

So, reading MS's docs on this sort of thing, I did:

```
Dim exists As Object = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\APLW.WSEngine", "CLSID", Nothing)
```

This *always* returns `Nothing`, in spite of GetTypeFromProgID working fine, and the key and value clearly being there in the reg. I've tried every variation I can think of, including using `ClassesRoot.GetValue` in the method instead of the generic version of `GetValue`, trying various keys and values...

Ok, what am I doing wrong? I assume it's something trivial...

Comment: Please see [**my**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34982947/how-do-i-check-to-see-if-a-registry-entry-exists/34983211#34983211) answer it may be of help.

Comment: It was indeed, thanks!